# Is ART sandboxing application like Dalvik?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-runtime

I was wondering and googling for an answer, but I didn't find it. So, is newer ART sandboxing apps like Dalvik VM? To be more precise, can image from this link be applied for ART too? http://davidchang168.blogspot.rs/2012/07/android-vm-and-application.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, is newer ART sandboxing apps like Dalvik VM?

The Dalvik VM does not sandbox apps. The Android OS sandboxes apps. ART changes the nature of what is executed (AOT-compiled bytecode instead of JIT-compiled bytecode) in the app. It does not change the nature of the Android process model and the sandboxing approach.

> To be more precise, can image from this link be applied for ART too?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> To be more precise, can image from this link be applied for ART too?
>   [image]

You second question is irrelevant to the first one (sandboxing).
ART, like Dalvik, exploits the [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) mechanism, and actually it is even better than its predecessor. This is because the `oat code` is pageable, whereas the `JITted` code is not, as it is dynamically produced. Therefore, not just framework multimedia, ie images, but also code can be shared between applications.

For this to make sense, imagine the class `String`. I bet it is being used by 99% of Android applications. Therefore its code and a small heap of objects is created once, while a device boots up, on `boot.oat` and `boot.art` images. These images can then be shared among applications, and contain more classes than just the `String` class.

When an application attempts to modify something in such a class the `copy-on-write` mechanism ensures that the application will get a separate copy of that particular page, while the rest of the apps can continue sharing the original copy of the page.

This `page-ability` is good for both memory and performance.